# XQuery simple malformed query

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm working on a larger XQuery and am pulling a blank on how to get the piece of data I need.  I am trying to find all the pids for projects a person is working on.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
    <project pid="p123">
        <leader>
            <name>Amanda</name>
        </leader>
        <analyst>
            <name>Bob</name>
        </analyst>
    </project>
    <project pid="p456">
        <leader>
            <name>John</name>
        </leader>
     </project>
     <project pid="p789">
         <leader>
             <name>David</name>
         </leader>
         <analyst>
             <name>Amanda</name>
         </analyst>
     </project>
</projects>
```

So the result, not in this format, is Amanda to be with p123, p789, Bob with p123, John with p456, and David with p789.  I just started XQuery this week so I'm still new to this language.  Thanks

EDIT:
The form I'm trying to get is

```
<workforce>
    <emp roles, name>
        <project>
            <proj>(Project ids go here)</proj>
        </project>
     </emp>
 <workforce>
```

I can get it into this form but the  portion I can't get.  I need to link the employees to there current projects.

Comment: Please show what you have so far and explain where you're stuck. (Otherwise this question is of the categoy "plz give me teh codez", which is generally frowned upon here on SO.)

Comment: Edited it for clarity, I know it wasn't super clear.

Comment: The problem is not that you have not been clear (though adding the desired output is a good thing). The problem is that your question does not convey that you actually tried to solve this on your own, but rather that you are looking for code you can simply copy and paste.

Comment: To add on what Tomalak said: Please show us your "malformed XQuery". We then will hopefully be able to turn it into a non-malformed XQuery.

Comment: Just as importantly, showing the bad code demonstrates the intended logic, rather than relying on it being inferred via reading input and output. Right now, it's hard to tell if an answer is correct, because we don't know what your intended logic is, only what you want as a result (and even that not precisely -- should the project IDs be space-separated? In different elements? etc).

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, it is better to post what you tried, in order for us to have a look at it and fix what is wrong.  But well, for a simple query, here is a possibility to solve your problem:

```
let $in :=
   <projects>
      <project pid="p123">
         <leader>
            <name>Amanda</name>
         </leader>
         <analyst>
            <name>Bob</name>
         </analyst>
      </project>
      <project pid="p456">
         <leader>
            <name>John</name>
         </leader>
      </project>
      <project pid="p789">
         <leader>
            <name>David</name>
         </leader>
         <analyst>
            <name>Amanda</name>
         </analyst>
      </project>
   </projects>
for $n in distinct-values($in/project/*/name)
return
   <person name="{ $n }"> {
      for $p in $in/project[*/name = $n]
      return
         <project pid="{ $p/@pid }" position="{ name($p/*[name eq $n]) }"/>
   }
   </person>
```

It is not exactly the output as you described, but I could not make sense of it.  Evaluating the above expression produces the following result:

```
<person name="Amanda">
   <project pid="p123" position="leader"/>
   <project pid="p789" position="analyst"/>
</person>
<person name="Bob">
   <project pid="p123" position="analyst"/>
</person>
<person name="John">
   <project pid="p456" position="leader"/>
</person>
<person name="David">
   <project pid="p789" position="leader"/>
</person>
```

That is, for each distinct name, create a `person` element, and for each project that name appears on, create a `project` element with its PID and the position of the current name.